# How to target only one browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to set a height for a div only for one browser, so it doesn't look weird in Firefox or whatever.

Here is an example:

```css
#example {
  height: 200px; <!--How can I target Safari for example?--> 
  height: 250px; <!--How can I target Firefox for example?--> 
  height: 300px; <!--How can I target IE for example?--> 
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img src="example.png">
  <p>Just some text.</p>
  <p>Click <a href="www.example.com">here</a> to visit www.example.com</p>
</div>
```

I've already tried `-moz-height: 250px;` but it didn't work.

Comment: Something else that might help is [`box-sizing`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), which can instruct each browser to apply height and width in the same manner.

Comment: Browser sniffing is a pretty bad approach. No reason a page would look (much) different on any browser when the markup is written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.appName
```

it will return always the same value for all browsers. I've tested on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all browsers show `Netscape`. But if you want to target specific browsers you can use this code

Firefox `navigator.userAgent.includes("Firefox");`

Safari `navigator.userAgent.includes("Safari");`

Chrome `navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome");`

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use **JavaScript**. There is a string that you can access called `navigator.appName`. You can just put this:

```
if(navigator.appName === "Google Chrome")
    // Do whatever here
```

replacing ***Microsoft Internet Explorer*** with your target browser.

I really hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional comments. So you tell the code to use a certain stylesheet for a particular browser. [Here's an article about it](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/advanced/conditionalcomments/).

Here's an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal_style.css">
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie_style.css"><![endif]-->
```

Note: this only works with Internet Explorer. If you want to do it for some other browser you need to use JavaScript. Here's an example of JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="stylesheet" href="normal_style.css">
if (navigator.appName === "Mozilla Firefox") {
    document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttribute("href", "special_style.css"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the navigator object and get the browser.

```
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
```

Then

```
document.getElementById("example").style.height= y;
```

"y" it is a variable whose value changes depending on the browser.